# How could I solve $\sum_{k=3}^7 k^2-1$ by using the formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic

This afternoon I am dealin with with this question:
$$\sum_{k=3}^7 k^2-1$$
When I using [Microsoft Math solver for this question](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/%60displaystyle%60sum_%7B%20k%20%3D%20%203%20%20%7D%5E%7B%207%20%20%7D%20%60left(%20%7B%20k%20%20%7D%5E%7B%202%20%20%7D%20%20-1%20%60right)) or just plug in every numbers, I get 130. However, when I using the formular equation, I got 140.

The formula I use is on page 420 on [big ideas math algebra 2](https://bim.easyaccessmaterials.com/?level=13.00&p=417)

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctfx2.png)

This is the work:
$$
a_3=9-1=8
$$

$$
a_7=49-1=48
$$

$$
n\frac{a_3+a_n}{2}
=5\frac{8+48}{2}
=140
$$

I wonder is there anything I do wrong in the qustion. How could I fix it? What knowledge points I did not get?

Comment: I'm not sure what formula you're trying to use, but it looks like it's assuming that $k^2-1$ forms an arithmetic sequence (a sequence with a common difference, like $1, 5, 9, 13, \ldots$). Since $k^2-1$ isn't an arithmetic sequence, such a formula cannot be used.

Comment: @BrianTung Now I add the source of the formula, thanks for your comment.

Comment: "However, when I using the formula equation" : what formula equation?  Please edit your posting to specify exactly what formula equation that you are referring to, and what the source (i.e. Math book, Math class, webpage) of the equation is.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum (k^2-1)$$ or $$\left(\sum k^2\right)-1?$$

Comment: The link that you provided doesn't show any formula.

Comment: @user2661923 it is on the bottom on page 420

Comment: assuming you mean $\sum(k^2-1)$ the answer is 130

Comment: The link that you provided brings up a web page entitled *Big Ideas Math*.  How do I get from that webpage to the formula that you are referring to?

Comment: This link appears to require registration. No thanks. It definitely looks like you're trying to use a formula for an arithmetic sequence on a sequence that is not arithmetic. That will give an incorrect answer.

Comment: @BrianTung now I add the image

Comment: @HanHan your sequence is ***NOT*** arithmetic. list out all the terms and find their differences. You should find that they are *different*, meaning that you cant use the arithmetic sum formula on them!

Comment: To elaborate: The arithmetic sequence sum formula works because the average of an arithmetic sequence (a finite one) is equal to the average of the first and last value. For example, the average of $1, 5, 9, 13, 17$ is equal to the average of $1$ and $17$—namely, $\frac{1+17}{2} = 9$. Try it out with a few arithmetic sequences. That is why the formula can safely rely only on the first and last values. If the sequence is not arithmetic (as is the case with $k^2-1$), then you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you mean $\sum_{k=3}^7 (k^2-1)$

The terms in the sequence are $3^2-1 = 8,4^2-1 = 15,5^2-1 = 24,6^2-1 = 35$ and $7^2-1 = 48$.

$8, 15, 24, 35, 48$ does not form an arithmetic sequence so that formula does not apply. $15-8 = 7$ and $24-15 = 9$, and since $7 \neq 9$, this is not an arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are asking $\sum^7_{k=3}(k^2-1)$.
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum^7_{k=3}(k^2-1)&=\sum^7_{k=1}k^2-\sum^2_{k=1}k^2-\sum^7_{k=3}1 \\
&=\frac{7(7+1)(2\times 7+1)}{6}-\frac{2(2+1)(2\times 2+1)}{6}-5 \\
&=140 - 5 - 5\\
&=130
\end{align*}
$$